# .include? doesn't raise when I add identical strings

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to downcase name before include is ran. Calling it on push has caused some weird behavior: It will add the second Jack to the list if it starts with a capitol, but will not add it if the second Jack is lowercase. How can I downcase name before the include check?

```
$list = []
def hand_out_gift(name)
  if $list.include?name
    raise "u can't get more than one present!"
  else
    $list.push(name.downcase)
    puts "Here you go #{name} :)"
  end
end
hand_out_gift("Jack")
hand_out_gift("Mary")
hand_out_gift("Jill")
hand_out_gift("Jack")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downcase it early in your function:

```
def hand_out_gift(name)
  key = name.downcase
  if $list.include? key
    raise "u can't get more than one present!"
  else
    $list.push key
    puts "Here you go #{name} :)"
  end
end
```

Aside: avoid using global variables like that.

Comment: Should I have used an instance variable instead here?